# Why do all the start menu tiles in Windows 10 have the same color?

Tags: windows-10, colors, tiles

I recently (and regrettably) upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10. Now all the tiles in start menu got the same color, which is a bit annoying in terms of usability. Is this a bug due to the upgrade process and is there a way to change tile-colors?
[image]

Comment: [Here](http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/373895-can-i-change-colors-live-tiles-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. You can change accent colour but not individual tile colours.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was wondering, because if you search the web for "windows 10" screenshots, most pictures you'll find show colored tiles. Seems they took it out on last minute before release.